# Incorporating vegetarianism in primary school teaching

Tags: outreach

How would you incorporate ideas of veganism and vegetarianism as a primary school teacher (ages 6-10), without promoting potential conflict with the parents of the children. As I see it, a soft introduction to these principles would be simply to discuss pet/animal protection, which is much closer to the kids. But should you go further? Are you aware of any (on-line available, free) resources to use for such an attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for educators is to follow the curriculum to maintain professional standards. During periods of instruction covering health and diet, veganism and vegetarianism should be included in the curriculum. However, there are dangers that such attempts at promotion of a teacher's viewpoint or lifestyle outside of the curriculum and without proper balance could become indoctrination.

There is a [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8954596/) published on the NIH's National Library of Medicine site addressing this very question.

> Indoctrination when teaching sustainable nutrition involves one-sided teaching approaches or materials that support the teachers’ beliefs. As an example, a vegan biology teacher may choose teaching materials that focus on the benefits of a vegan diet, without considering counterarguments. These materials would solely give information on the drawbacks of meat consumption and the benefits of vegan diets, but hide information on the benefits of meat consumption and limitations of veganism.